# Oracle Home issue while installing OBIEE 12C

Tags: obiee, oracle-home

I've trouble to installing Oracle Business Intelligence at setting Oracle Home
path, and the error is as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdnxE.jpg)
Also i tried to change the path in different directory ,and the error changed as below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgfHW.jpg)
My Environment variables is as below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hYYv.jpg)

Comment: What kind of Windows is this?

Comment: Windows 10 and the OBIEE is 12.2.1.0.0

Comment: Did you just abandon this?  You know that StackOverflow only works when people actually participate and that includes marking answers as being the correct ones so other users can benefit.

Comment: I've found that the versions of My weblogic and OBI has a little bit different , so i'm downloading the other version and want to give it try.

Comment: The version of my weblogic was 12.2.1.3

Comment: Doesn't matter. Windows 10 is NOT supported! You are installing a whole farm of servers on an opersting system for desktop work and gaming. It is not a server OS. Period.

Comment: But i've successfully installed OBIEE 12c on Win 10 and the just issue was the version of my weblogic which is solved by re-installing a new one.

Comment: Ok then go ahead. Just know that nothing you will face in terms of issues will be covered by Oracle because you're not supported. And most people will also stop answering once tbey know you are on an unsupportrd OS.

Answer (score 0):

**NO** Windows Desktop operating system is a certified host for an Oracle BI installation!

https://dimensionality.ch/2017/05/06/installing-oracle-bi-on-windows-7-8-10/

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly because you haven't yet installed the weblogic server.
You need first to install the fusion middleware infrastructure.

```
java –jar fmw_12.2.1.0.0_infrastructure.jar
```